# Reasonable handling scheme for Node.JS async errors in unusual places

Tags: node.js, error-handling

In Java, I am used to try..catch, with finally to cleanup unused resources.

In Node.JS, I don't have that ability.

Odd errors can occur for example the database could shut down at any moment, any single table or file could be missing, etc.

With nested calls to `db.query(..., function(err, results){...`, it becomes tedious to call `if(err) {send500(res); return}` every time, *especially* if I have to cleanup resources, for example `db.end()` would definitely be appropriate.

How can one write code that makes async catch and finally blocks both be included?

I am already aware of the ability to restart the process, but I would like to use that as a last-resort only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full answer to this is pretty in depth, but it's a combination of:

- consistently handling the `error` positional argument in callback functions. Doubling down here should be your first course of action.

  - You will see @izs refer to this as "boilerplate" because you need a lot of this whether you are doing callbacks or promises or flow control libraries. There is no great way to totally avoid this in node due to the async nature. However, you can minimize it by using things like helper functions, connect middleware, etc. For example, I have a helper callback function I use whenever I make a DB query and intend to send the results back as JSON for an API response. That function knows how to handle errors, not found, and how to send the response, so that reduces my boilerplate substantially.
- use `process.on('uncaughtExcepton')` as per [@izs's blog post](http://blog.izs.me/post/65712662830/restart-node-js-servers-on-domain-errors-sensible-fud)
- use `try/catch` for the occasional synchronous API that throws exceptions. Rare but some libraries do this.
- consider using [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html). Domains will get you closer to the java paradigm but so far I don't see that much talk about them which leads me to expect they are not widely adopted yet in the node community.
- consider using [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). While not directly related, it generally goes hand in hand with this type of production robustness.
- some libraries have top-level error events. For example, if you are using mongoose to talk to mongodb and the connection suddenly dies, the connection object will emit an error event

Here's an example. The use case is a REST/JSON API backed by a database.

```
//shared error handling for all your REST GET requests
function normalREST(res, error, result) {
  if (error) {
    log.error("DB query failed", error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
    return;
  }
  if (!result) {
    res.status(404).send();
    return;
  }
  res.send(result); //handles arrays or objects OK
}


//Here's a route handler for /users/:id
function getUser(req, res) {
  db.User.findById(req.params.id, normalREST.bind(null, res));
}
```

And I think my takeaway is that overall in JavaScript itself, error handling is basically woefully inadequte. In the browser, you refresh the page and get on with your life. In node, it's worse because you're trying to write a robust and long-lived server process. There is a [completely epic issue comment on github](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5114#issuecomment-15328612) that goes into great detail how things are just fundamentally broken. I wouldn't get your hopes up of ever having JavaScript code you can point at and say "Look, Ma, state-of-the-art error handling". That said, in practice if you follow the points I listed above, empirically you can write programs that are robust enough for production.

See also [The 4 Keys to 100% Uptime with node.js](http://engineering.spanishdict.com/blog/2013/12/20/the-4-keys-to-100-uptime-with-nodejs).

Comment: *"consistently handling the error positional argument in callback functions."* That's the part I'm interested in, as it relates to HTTP servers. Code samples of real-world effective solutions would be great. That way I don't have to invent my own ideas on how the error argument would be handled.

Comment: Example added. I don't think node can entirely match a synchronous language with good exceptions like java or python in terms of how small and centralized error handling can be. Same is true for C or Go, but I think the above is decent.

Comment: I agree, error handling will never reach the same level of simplicity without a [complex language change for the sole purpose of imitation](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2422).